# System.Web.Compilation.CompilationException Error compiling a resource required to service this request .Net on MAC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, xamarin.ios, mono

System.Web.Compilation.CompilationException
CS0012: The type `System.Net.Http.HttpMethod' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly`System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Description: Error compiling a resource required to service this request. Review your source file and modify it to fix this error.
Details: CS0012: The type `System.Net.Http.HttpMethod' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly`System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
Error origin: Compiler
Error source file: /Users/x/x/x/x/x/x/Areas/HelpPage/Views/Help/DisplayTemplates/ApiGroup.cshtml

Exception stack trace:
  at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly

```
    (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath, System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options) [0x002fa] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/AssemblyBuilder.cs:853 
  at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/AssemblyBuilder.cs:731 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GenerateAssembly (System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder abuilder, System.Web.Compilation.BuildProviderGroup group, System.Web.VirtualPath vp, System.Boolean debug) [0x00202] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/BuildManager.cs:826 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BuildInner (System.Web.VirtualPath vp, System.Boolean debug) [0x00106] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/BuildManager.cs:451
```

Error source context:
Error lines: 10, 27, 36

```
8: @{
9:     var controllerDocumentation = ViewBag.DocumentationProvider != null ? 
10:         ViewBag.DocumentationProvider.GetDocumentation(Model.Key) : 
11:         null;
12: }
```

Comment: Did you try to read the error, or did you just post it here?

Answer (score 0):

well expand your references in project, then check wether the refernce is added or not if not then  right click on it and then add the required reference

[image]

[image]